# how to dynamic register spring bean and set as primary

Tags: java, spring

It's easy to register. 
Just need to call `beanFactory.registerSingleton(beanName, object);`.

But `beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName).setPrimary(true)` will throw **NPE**.

**So how to dynamically register spring bean and set as primary?**

Answer (score 4):

You have to build BeanDefinition. 
e.g.

```
BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(object.class)
                        .addPropertyValue("nameProperty1", propertyValue1)
                        .addPropertyValue("nameProperty2", propertyValue2)

BeanDefinition beanDefinition = builder.getBeanDefinition();
beanDefinition.setPrimary(Boolean.TRUE);

beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
```

So you can now get bean "beanName" from application context.

Answer (score 1):

Here a full sample because I had to search and combine with others answers to make it work fully

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Config implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  public static final String MOCK_CLASS = "MyClassMock";
  public static final String MY_CLASS = "MyClass";

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
    final var beanDefinition = BeanDefinitionBuilder
        .rootBeanDefinition(MyClass.class)
        .getBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setPrimary(true);
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(MOCK_CLASS, beanDefinition);
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    beanFactory.registerSingleton(MOCK_CLASS, new MyClass());
    beanFactory.registerSingleton(MY_CLASS, new MyClass());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
beanFactory.initializeBean(object, beanName);
beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(object, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
```

and then

```
beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName).setPrimary(true)
```

Comment: it not works, throw exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'xxx' available